# Combine multiple VLOOKUPs

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

How would I combine these together into one?:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"No Match")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B12,Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE),"No Match")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!G:H,2,FALSE),"No Match")
```

These are just three but eventually I would need 12 in total to be joined as these are searching team names and there are 12 teams in total.

Comment: data would help, its seems you are using the wrong formula for the task

Comment: Why is the first parameter to vlookup a range? vlookup takes a single value as it's first parameter ... not a range.

Comment: Post some data as Steven mentioned.  However, from the formulas, it appears you are trying to search a team name in one of 3 (er 12) lists ?  Why do you have 12 lists? why not just a single list ?

Comment: Ok so the reason for the 12 lists is that i have a database which at present has no team names but does have staff names. To get around this and allow staff to search by team not just agent i have created a new column and will be housing this formula within that column. The formula then searches the individual team columns in sheet 2 and then places the relevant team name next to that agent in sheet 1.

Comment: I can't share the exact database as it is too large but also has sensitive data in it. I have uploaded a example here>> http://www.filedropper.com/robsreportteamsearch. I will also look at implementing the answers already here and see if they work. The formula i supplied above do work and do what they are supposed to it's just they only search 1 team where i need it to search 12. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to work through each of the pairs of columns in order, for an example of three pairs, just:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!D:E,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!G:H,2,0),"No Match")))
```

assuming that it is B2 that is to be your search term (lookup_value) and that the formula above is in Row2. Where ranges are used as the search term in VLOOKUP the row value used is the one in which the formula resides ("implied intercept").

It is generally preferred (eg a tad shorter) to use a version like this instead:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!D:E,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!G:H,2,0),"No Match")))
```

and copy the formula down, when B2 adjusts automatically to B3 etc. (Shorter is also why I tend to prefer `0` to `FALSE`.)

As mentioned by @Ditto, your data has an unusual layout. Unless you have special reasons for twelve pairs of columns it would appear that just one pair should be sufficient as you seem not to be attempting to place any condition upon which team is searched for which "B2 value". Stacked in ColumnsA:B (by all means with spaces to separate them and labels for the separate teams) there would be no requirement to replicate one of your formulae, this should be sufficient in place of all 12:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"No Match")
```

If it can be guaranteed that a result *will* be found somewhere (or `#N/A` accepted if not, instead of "No Match") this can be further simplified to:

```
  =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: How do i give you some rep for this, you've helped me out massively?

Comment: @Jamesmook to give pnuts rep for this, vote up his answer with the up arrow above the number to the left of his answer and click the check mark to mark his answer as THE answer. This gives him rep and also marks the question as answered so those of us who are looking for unanswered questions don't come here to find that pnuts has beaten us to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"No Match")
>    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B12,Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE),"No Match")
>    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!G:H,2,FALSE),"No Match")

Would become:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),
>     IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B12,Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE),
>     IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!G:H,2,FALSE),"No Match")
>   )
>   )

Ultimately:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B12,Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,Sheet2!G:H,2,FALSE),"No Match")))

The result however will still be *No Match* as *"B2:B11"* and such are not accepted as *Lookup_value* inputs with the *VLOOKUP* function as mentioned by @Ditto.

Comment: Pnuts, You're a star!!! Your answer works like a dream! I was making things to difficult for myself and your answer is so simple, i don't know wjhy i didn't see it before. Thjis worked the best =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"No Match")